# What's the equivalent function for mLogit() if random effects are involved?

Tags: mixed-model, random-effects-model, multinomial-logit

`mLogit` is the function for running multinomial logistic regression in R.
What if we have random effects (mixed-effects model), what's the adequate function (and package) for this purpose?

Comment: This is about finding, indeed about recommending, a function in some unspecified language (perhaps R, but there is no good practice here except naming software) and as such is off-topic here. Please see advice in the Help Center. Such questions are off-topic on Stack Overflow too.

Comment: Secondary issue, but I'd be surprised if there is just one function to do this....

Comment: My bad, I added the fact that its R software. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but in my view it's still off-topic.

Comment: Thank you, but I could not find a reason to consider my question as off-topic?

Comment: Do you suggest I provide my own model?

Comment: Software-specific questions are off-topic unless there is a statistical question at their heart. I can't offer advice on what you should do in your problem. For a start, there may well be code that does exactly what you want, but I am no kind of R expert and (more importantly) finding or recommending it is not what any SE site does for you. Two sound reasons for that (1) if there is software the usual searches should find it (2) what's good or even adequate is too much a matter of opinion.

Comment: @Aceracer You may have better luck on the [R-sig-mixed-models mailing list](https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-mixed-models)

Comment: Ah thank you for the clarification. I searched a lot into this before posting, but its ok I will keep searching. Thank you Nick and Jake

Comment: A [search of our site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=multinomial+logit+generalized+mixed+model+%5Br%5D) turns up answers.  One of them is embedded in a detailed question (with `R` code!).